# Page title for categories

Tags: category

While doing a Google search for a brand we carry, I noticed the page title had our name listed twice in the search results.  Is there something I can do to change the appearance of the title since obviously I don't want the name to appear twice.

http://vvcap.net/db/mOCAEIchArBxcm1gdYXH.htp

Answer (score 1):

I notice your site is not using Rich Snippets.  Add it to your site to get the results you're after.

You can use the Google Structured Data Tool to see how Google renders your snippets: https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/.

There are plenty of extensions and instructions out there for adding them to your Magento site.

Here is Google's explanation: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2722261?hl=en